# Is there any way to use same parameter in io:format?

Tags: erlang, format

Is there any construction or maybe other function to do something like this:

```
Var = "hello",
io:format("My text is ~s[1]. And again: ~s[1]", Var).
```

So the output will be:

> My text is hello. And again: hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the second parameter of io:format() should be a list.
2. you can do it this way:
   io:format("My text is ~s[1]. And again: ~s[1]", [Var, Var]).

Comment: Maybe i didn't write the question correctly. It was about using same parameter without adding it in list again.

Comment: You have to add it to list twice, that's just the way API looks like. But you should not be concerned about memory usage.  Erlang as functional will not create copy of `Var`, and just point to same memory twice. And creating such list is quite cheap also.

Comment: Well, thanks. In terms of readability it's not so good, though. It's all coming from my Python roots :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems overkill to me, but you could do something like:

```
Vars = lists:duplicate(3, "hello").
io:format("One: ~s, two: ~s, three: ~s.", Vars).
```